# Jetpack Compose TextField weird behavior when deleting text

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

This video explains better, please watch: [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wEr_BzNaR5TRrMXTUc117MZ1GwoohJGZ/view?usp=sharing)

The code is very simple:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Main() {
    var note by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            LoremIpsum(40).values.first() //generate a random string that contains 40 words
        )
    }

    TextField(value = note, onValueChange = { note = it })
}
```

I have tried pasting random strings and deleting them fast enough in a messaging app, to make sure that this problem does not cause by the soft keyboard/Google keyboard, and it's just working fine in the messaging app.

I don't understand why this could happen, could this be a bug with TextField?

You can download the project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w3dk4M89Et7TWeaP4OIKvSX5pf3MdC-3/view?usp=sharing), but basically, all the code has been posted above.

Comment: Looks like a bug, I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128)

Comment: Hope they fix it soon https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221636606